# Qt - QTreeWidgetItem not being edited

Tags: c++, qt

Why is my QTreeWidgetItem not being editable? I used this code to implement one:

```
ui->treeWidget->expandAll();
QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
item->setText(0, "Add details about your Bug");
bug->addChild(item);
ui->treeWidget->editItem(item, 0);
```

Comment: bug is QTreeWidgetItem in ui->treeWidget?

Comment: Yes, and it's set to be the parent, and 'item' is set to be it's child.  What I want to do is as soon as this new item is added, it will go on an edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set editable to true in QTreeWidgetItem (default it's false):

```
ui->treeWidget->expandAll();
QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
item->setText(0, "Add details about your Bug");
item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
bug->addChild(item);
ui->treeWidget->editItem(item, 0);
```